# timings problems in hackerrank in "The Love-Letter Mystery" question

Tags: java

I am solving the "The Love-Letter Mystery" problem may be my logic is correct but it is showing the timings problems The Question is
[Question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fQv4.png).My solution for same is given below. It contains two functions one is ***theLoveLetterMystery(String s)*** which is returning sum_minimum_Steps and other is ***conversionCount(String s,int i,int j)*** which is returning int ***characterCount*** variable.It sums all the minimum steps to return the value

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the theLoveLetterMystery function below.
    static int theLoveLetterMystery(String s) {
        int startCounter=0,endCounter=(s.length()-1),sum_minimum_Steps=0;
        // s.charAt(startCounter)!=s.charAt(endCounter)
        while(startCounter!=endCounter)
        {
            if(s.charAt(startCounter)!=s.charAt(endCounter))
            {
                //minimun steps function executes
                sum_minimum_Steps+=conversionCount(s,startCounter,endCounter);
            }else{
                startCounter++;
                endCounter--;
            }
        }
        return sum_minimum_Steps;
    }
    static int conversionCount(String s,int i,int j) {
        int charStartAscii=(int)s.charAt(i);
        int charEndAscii=(int)s.charAt(j);
        int characterCount=0;
        while(charStartAscii!=charEndAscii)
        {
        charEndAscii--;
        characterCount++;
        }
        return characterCount;
    }    
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int q = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();

            int result = theLoveLetterMystery(s);

            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the constraints are missing for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the assumption we are working on an alphabet of 26 letters(range a - z) "The Love-Letter Mystery" question is about find the minimum number of operations consisting of decrement of value 1 of a letter (for example d -> c and excluding letter a) to convert a string to a palindrome string. This can be obtained adding the absolute int differences between chars standing in positions i and n - i - 1 where n is the length of the string and iterating over half of the string. Below the code:

```
public static int conversionCount(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    int length = s.length();

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i) {
            count += Math.abs((int) (arr[i] - arr[length - i - 1]));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note: I tested it in hackerrank passing all tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
function theLoveLetterMystery($s) {
    $s = strtoupper($s);
    $alpha = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X ','Y','Z');
$alpha_flip = array_flip($alpha);
    // Write your code here
        $i = 0;
        $j = strlen($s)-1;
        $sol = 0;
        while($i<$j){
             $sol += abs($alpha_flip[$s[$i]]-$alpha_flip[$s[$j]]);
            ++$i;
            --$j;
        }
        return $sol;

}
echo theLoveLetterMystery('abbc')// return 2
```